# programatically add two image to above my label

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a custom library : [CAPSPageMenu](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu) . Here I have one view controller and I programmatically add the name for that, the view has two tabs. When i click any tab that respective page will display below.

I have set the name and added the animation to swipe between two tabs. But now I need to add image on above of my label, how would I accomplish that?

[image]

Here is my code !:

```
var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu? // pager object

var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = [] // number view pager
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        pageSettings()

}
func pageSettings() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        let controller1 : UIViewController = UIViewController()
        controller1.title = "FAVOURITES"
        controllerArray.append(controller1)

        let controller2 : UIViewController = UIViewController()
        controller2.title = "RECENT SEARCH"
        controllerArray.append(controller2)


        let leftRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didLeftSwipe(_:)))
        leftRecognizer.direction = .Left
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(leftRecognizer)

        let rightRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didRightSwipe(_:)))
        rightRecognizer.direction = .Right
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(rightRecognizer)
    }
```

Like this i need to add image.As i mention the box above the two labels

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Are you trying to create a customized segmentedControl?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are used a custom library [CAPSPageMenu](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu), unfortunately what do you want to do is not available.

However with swift you can do extraordinary things such as expanding PageMenu directly in your code: (I've maded just an example but you can start from it):

Add this code at the bottom of your class or whatever you want:

```
extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: completion)  }

    func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: completion)
    }
}



extension CAPSPageMenu {
    func addImageOverMyMenuItem(index:Int,imageName:String) {
        if index>=0 && index<self.menuItems.count || self.menuItems[index].titleLabel!.frame.height>0 {
            var labelFrame = self.menuItems[index].titleLabel!.frame
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: imageName)!
            let bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
            labelFrame.origin.y = self.menuItems[index].frame.origin.y
            labelFrame.origin.x += (labelFrame.width/10)
            labelFrame.size.width -= (labelFrame.width/10)*2
            labelFrame.size.height = self.menuItems[index].titleLabel!.frame.size.height/3
            bgImage.frame = labelFrame
            bgImage.tag = 9999
            bgImage.alpha = 0.0
            self.menuItems[index].addSubview(bgImage)
            bgImage.fadeIn(completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                if finished {
                    // image is showed, do whatever you want 
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("Due to index out of range or titleLabel dont yet setted i cannot set image")
        }
    }

    func removeImageOverMyMenuItem(index:Int) {
            if index>=0 && index<self.menuItems.count {
                if let bgImage = self.menuItems[index].viewWithTag(9999) {
                    bgImage.fadeOut(completion: {
                        (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                        if finished {
                            bgImage.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
     }
  }
```

You can easily use to add an image:

```
pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(0, imageName: "search.png")
```

and to remove :

```
pageMenu?.removeImageOverMyMenuItem(0)
```

P.S. The result would be this:

[image]

So , finally following the official demo 1 project (PageMenuDemoStoryboard) in the **ViewController** at the method **viewDidAppear** i can add my images like this:

```
// Initialize scroll menu
pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(0, imageName: "search.png")
pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(1, imageName: "search.png")
pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(2, imageName: "search.png")
self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
...
```

And you obtain this result:

[image]

P.S.S. If it's not clear, I've made this example just using an image named "search.png" but you can use all images do you want to insert in your project.

Comment: Where i have to add this line `pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(0, imageName: "search.png")` ??

Comment: where do you want to insert your images?

Comment: Above my two labels. "Favourite" "Recent Search"

Comment: In your code, where do you customize var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu ? You dont report this code up, at the last lines try to add the images..

Comment: Where i will mention - to fix my image.Becasue above my text "Favourite" and above my text "Resent Search".Because if i add this line.Then how i will mention my image to display on above of my two labels

Comment: Probably there is a translation problem: what do you mean for on above of my label? Do you mean over your label? Or near to, explain it then I help you to make corrections..

Comment: please see my updaed post image.I have show there clearly

Comment: Now , if i add the line `pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(0, imageName: "search.png"`on below pagesetting method.Then how can i add two different images.I measn i have favourite and resent search know,So i need to add two different image.So how to add two different images

Comment: I dont need to change the image.I need show both image in above the text

Comment: I've update my answer. Check your personal code, the demo work well. Hope it can help you to solve.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano how to change the width height of that image?

Comment: i have added images using ur code but i want to change current menu tab to hover image how to do so @AlessandroOrnano

Answer (score 0):

You are using [PageMenu](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu), right?

Basically, PageMenu doesn't have the feature satisfy your needs.
If you want to use PageMenu, you have to modify this module.
Check MenuItemView Class in CAPSPageMenu.swift

Answer (score 0):

I have also customised `CAPSPageMenu` ,  using the answer of @Alessandro Ornano that helped me to add the image above text, so anyone using can also set width,height of image and also can set the position of image as per device by using code below.Hope it will help someone.

```
extension UIView {
func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 0.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: completion)  }

func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 0.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: completion)
  }
}
extension CAPSPageMenu {
func addImageOverMyMenuItem(index:Int,imageName:String) {
    if index>=0 && index<self.menuItems.count || self.menuItems[index].titleLabel!.frame.height>0 {
        var labelFrame = self.menuItems[index].titleLabel!.frame
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: imageName)!
        let bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
        labelFrame.origin.y = self.menuItems[index].frame.origin.y
        labelFrame.origin.x += (labelFrame.width/9)
        labelFrame.size.width -= (labelFrame.width/10)*5
        labelFrame.size.height = self.menuItems[index].titleLabel!.frame.size.height/3
        bgImage.frame = labelFrame

        bgImage.tag = 9999
        bgImage.alpha = 0.0


        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 480:
                print("iPhone Classic")
            case 960:
                print("iPhone 4 or 4S")
                bgImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:20 ,y :0), size: CGSize(width:30, height: 30))
            case 1136:
                print("iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C")
                bgImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:20 ,y :0), size: CGSize(width:35, height: 35))
            case 1334:
                print("iPhone 6 or 6S")
                bgImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:30 ,y :0), size: CGSize(width:35, height: 35))
            case 2208:
                print("iPhone 6+ or 6S+")
                bgImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:35 ,y :0), size: CGSize(width:35, height: 35))
            default:
                print("unknown")
                bgImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:40 ,y :0), size: CGSize(width:30, height: 30))
            }
        }


        self.menuItems[index].addSubview(bgImage)
        bgImage.fadeIn(completion: {
            (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            if finished {
                // image is showed, do whatever you want
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("Due to index out of range or titleLabel dont yet setted i cannot set image")
    }
}
 func removeImageOverMyMenuItem(index:Int) {
    if index>=0 && index<self.menuItems.count {
        if let bgImage = self.menuItems[index].viewWithTag(9999) {
            bgImage.fadeOut(completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                if finished {

                    bgImage.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            })
        }
    }
  }
}


extension UIDevice {
    var iPhone: Bool {
        return UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    }
    enum ScreenType: String {
        case iPhone4
        case iPhone5
        case iPhone6
        case iPhone6Plus
        case unknown
    }
    var screenType: ScreenType {
        guard iPhone else { return .unknown }
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 960:
            return .iPhone4
        case 1136:
            return .iPhone5
        case 1334:
            return .iPhone6
        case 2208:
            return .iPhone6Plus

        default:
            return .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily use to add an image in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
 pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :70), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)), pageMenuOptions: menuParam)
        pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(index: 0, imageName: "detail.png")
        pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(index: 1, imageName: "gallery.png")
        pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(index: 2, imageName: "time.png")
        pageMenu?.addImageOverMyMenuItem(index: 3, imageName: "map.png")
```

Result :[image]